# Get query string in laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a problem here I send the date via url, so my url becomes like this

```
localhost:8000/info/transaksi/89?start_date=2019-09-20&end_date=2019-12-20
```

I want to take my time to be a variable containing something like this

```
$var = ?start_date=2019-09-20&end_date=2019-12-20
```

can it be posible?

or can I replace my web.php url request on the controller?

```
localhost:8000/info/transaksi/89?start_date=2019-09-20&end_date=2019-12-20
```

be like this

```
sandbox/synch/account/89?start_date=2019-09-20&end_date=2019-12-20
```

i'm only need **start_date=2019-09-20&end_date=2019-12-20**

i try with

```
$input  = $request->all();
```

but  it produces a different format because it becomes an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get query string:

```php
$uri = \Request::getRequestUri();
$query = parse_url($uri)['query'];
```

`$query` is the query string.

Answer (score 1):

get explicitly data.

```
$start_date = request()->start_date;
$end_date = request()->end_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Get raw query string:

```
$request->getQueryString()
```